# Theta Join in Relational Algebra Correctness

Tags: algebra, relational, relational-algebra

Considering these two tables:

**Band** (band_id, band_name)

**Band_Member** (band_id, member_name, dob, country, sex)

**The task:** List the names of band members and the names of the bands they are in using the theta Join.

Well, my doubt is in the step to show only the band_name and member_name after the join.

This is how I've done the theta-join: σ Band_Member.band_id = Band.band_id (Band_member x Band)

And this is how I think it might be correct to show only the band_name and member_name:

Π band_name, member_name (σ Band_Member.band_id = Band.band_id (Band_member x Band))

**EDIT:**
I also wonder if it is correct to write the Cartesian Product of the same task in these ways:

Π band_name, member_name (Band_Member x Band)

**OR**

Π member_name (Band_Member) x Π band_name (Band_Member)

Comment: A theta join is not necessary for this, why must you use one?

Comment: Well, basically because my teacher wants us to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Π band_name, member_name (σ Band_Member.band_id = Band.band_id (Band_member × Band))
```

shows all band members of each band.

```
Π band_name, member_name (Band_Member x Band)
```

This lists every member of any band for every band, whether they are members of that band or not. That is not the same as your earlier expression.

```
Π member_name (Band_Member) x Π band_name (Band_Member)
```

This is a relation containing every member of any band for every band that has a member (which is a subset of all bands). This is not the same thing as either of your earlier expressions.

The more idiomatic way of doing your first expression is a natural join:

```
Π band_name, member_name (Band_Member ⋈ Band)
```

which is the same thing as your first expression.

Comment: I couldn't find the symbol you wrote, that's why I did it with the selection operator. In this case, the third expression would be a more correct way of simply doing the Cartesian Product between both tables and showing the band_member and band_name columns?

Comment: No, `(Band_Member ⋈ Band)` means `(σ (where every attribute with the same names in every table are equal) (Band_member × Band))`.

Comment: That would be the 4th expression wouldn't it? I meant this one: **Π member_name (Band_Member) x Π band_name (Band_Member)**

Comment: `Π member_name (Band_Member) x Π band_name (Band_Member)` is a relation, not a list. It associates every band member with every band **that has a member**. `Π band_name, member_name (Band_member × Band)` associates every band member with every band, even if they are not a member of that band and even if a band has no members. They are not the same.

Comment: Oh, I got it know. The first expression doesn't show bands that don't have any band_members or band_members that don't have a band does it?